# How to locate only the emails out of the below elements using xpath?

Tags: xpath

Is there any way to locate only the emails using xpath out of the elements pasted below? I can't get any idea. I tried to reach out with a faulty one, though.

```
//div[@id="tab-1"]//h2/text()
```

Elements within which emails are stored:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Detail Keyence Sensor EV-108M</h2>
                            Keyence Sensor<br>
 <br>
 EV-130F<br>
 EV-12M<br>
 EV-130M<br>
 EV-112MC<br>
 EV-112U<br>
 EV-112UC<br>
 EV-11 8F<br>
 EV-118M<br>
 EV-118MC<br>
 EV-118U<br>
 EV-118UC<br>
 EV-30M<br>
 <br>
 Untuk harga dan stock hubungi kami<br>
 <br>
 PT. CERAH RAIH SEJAHTERA<br>
 Jl. R.S. Fatmawati No. 72 Taman Pondok Labu<br>
 Lt.1 Blok B 28-29 Jakarta 12450 Indonesia<br>
 Telp : 6221-2765 0033 - 7062 0128<br>
 Fax : 6221-2765 0034<br>
 E-mail : salescrs@ indo.net.id<br>
 E-mail : cerahraihsejahtera@ yahoo.co.id<br>
 <br>
 Sales Dept<br>
 HP : 081399026841<br>
 HP : 081298155774                            <div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: How does your solution fail?

Comment: It only locates the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below `XPath`

```
//div[@id="tab-1"]//text()[starts-with(., "E-mail")]
```

to get

```
E-mail : salescrs@ indo.net.id
E-mail : cerahraihsejahtera@ yahoo.co.id
```

If you want to get only emails, you can try

```
substring(//div[@id="tab-1"]//text()[starts-with(., "E-mail")][1], 10)
substring-after(//div[@id="tab-1"]//text()[starts-with(., "E-mail")][1], "E-mail : ")
```

to get `alescrs@ indo.net.id`

and

```
substring(//div[@id="tab-1"]//text()[starts-with(., "E-mail")][2], 10)
substring-after(//div[@id="tab-1"]//text()[starts-with(., "E-mail")][2], "E-mail : ")
```

to get `cerahraihsejahtera@ yahoo.co.id`

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your kind response. Now, I'm giving it a try and let you know, sir.

Comment: You left me dumbfounded, sir. I never thought that it would be possible so easily. I'm very sad that I could not hit the upvote button million times. Thankssssssssss a lot sir.